# Add a point in INPUT app that is not on my current position

Tags: gps, mergin-maps

I have a project that I have uploaded into the INPUT app. Is there a way to add a point in one layer that is not at my current position?
When I press the "RECORD" button it takes me to my position according to the GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you move the map and centre it around the point you want to record, it should capture the centre of the map as the recorded point.